# How can I use multiple IF functions in Excel 2010?

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function

Well, I am putting multiple `=IF` functions in a particular cell in Excel 2010. The `Value if True` part of the function is `A18*0.5`, however when I put more =IFs in the cell then the `Value if True` is basically ignored, and so it just says `TRUE` instead of my selected value, if it is true.

```
=IF(F2>=6,A18*0.5) =IF(F2=5,A18*0.6) =IF(F2=4,A18*0.7) =IF(F2=3,A18*0.8) =IF(F2=2,A18*0.9) =IF(F2=1,A18)
```

There is one less argument, which is the `Value if False`. I tried to get rid of that, to see if everything in the argument would be fair but it's still the same result.

Just to confirm, if cell F2 says anything higher than 6 (including 6 itself) than it will say the function of `=A18*0.5`, and if it isn't, it will say the respected `=IF` function in the cell.

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: Your question is unclear. Please tell us what the expected result is (what you're trying to accomplish). It looks like your are putting multiple formulas into one cell which won't work. Look up AND and OR boolean logic if you want to combine conditions.

Comment: I made it a little clearer I hope...

Comment: Did you mean this: =IF(F2>=6,A18*0.5,IF(F2=5,A18*0.6,somethingelse))?

Comment: Yes, that works a lot better now. Thank you. :)

Comment: Nesting is what you need here! you cannot have multiple formula's in a cell unless you nest.

Comment: To help you understand better, here is a very good explanation of using the [IF function](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/if-function-HP010342586.aspx) in Excel. It even explains nesting the function.

Answer (score 1):

It looks as if you want to nest your conditions:

```
=IF(F2>=6,A18*0.5,IF(F2=5,A18*0.6,somethingelse)
```

Note that in your specific case you could simplify to

```
=IF(F2>=6,A18*0.5,A18*(1.1-F2/10))
```

No more nested formulas ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Two other options:

```
=A18*CHOOSE(F2,1,0.9,0.8,0.7,0.6,0.5)
```

Or use a lookup table. Build a table like in the attached screenshot, with the values that can be in F2 in the left column and the corresponding values in the next column, sorted ascending by the left hand column.  In my sample, cell A18 has the value 1.

[image: In my sample, A18 has the value 1]

Then you can use

```
=A18*VLOOKUP(F2,H2:I7,2,TRUE)
```