# Having one cell to reference different cells based on another call's value

Tags: worksheet-function

I am looking for a formula that allows one call to reference a specific cell based on the value of another cell.

For instance 
If cell A1=10 (I manually put in this value), Cell B2=C3.
If Cell A1=12 Cell B2=C4
If Cell A1=14 Cell B2=C5
If Cell A1=16 Cell B2=C6
And so on.

I was able to accomplish the first instance (If Cell A1=10 Cell B2=C3) using the IF command

```
=IF(A1=10,C3)
```

But if any other number is in Cell A1, it just displays `False`.  How can I get it to reference different cells based on the value of A1?

Comment: Hello Dave,  Thank you for the quick reply.  I went to the link, have been playing with it but can't figure out how to write the second part of logic.  can you give me an example of what you mean?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I use multiple IF functions in Excel 2010?](http://superuser.com/questions/592404/how-can-i-use-multiple-if-functions-in-excel-2010)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a utility table somewhere in your worksheet, with two columns:

- The value of A1
- The cell to reference

It could look like this:

[image]

Then you can use the `VLOOKUP` function to search the ref table for A1's value and get the cell reference:

`VLOOKUP(A1,F1:G5,2)`

Finally, you need to convert this reference to an actual cell reference using the `INDIRECT` function.

The final B2 function will look like this (assuming your ref table is in F1:G5):

`=INDIRECT(VLOOKUP(A1,F1:G5,2))`

Comment: Thank you so much!  This is exactly what I needed and worked perfectly.  I would have never been able to figure that out on my own.  You are an excell genius!

Comment: @vince if this is the answer please mark it (green tick)

Answer (score 0):

Use this formula in B2

```
=INDEX(C:C,A1-(((A1-10)/2)+7))
```

[image]

Comment: Hello, I tried this formula and i got 0 for everything regardless of what value is in A1

Comment: @Vince I am not sure why.  As you can see from the photo I added it is working.

Comment: Hello Scott,I must have done something wrong on my end. I used the formula and reference table Atzmon provided above and it is working very well.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: @Vince no problems, Make sure you mark his answer as correct by clicking the check mark by his answer.

Comment: Thank you, I will, but it seems like the wrong term as with excel there are more than one way to go about doing things.   I liked Atzmon's code because it seemed to be the solution that summed up things and allowed me to expand on it easily in the future.

Thanks again.

Comment: @Vince the way this site is set up.  The correct answer is chosen by the Person who asked the question, this should be the answer that was used.  Then the community as a whole can use the voting to upvote or downvote the answers as they see fit.  there are many times that the selected correct answer is not the one with the most votes.  So by Choosing one above the other only states that it is the one you used, giving us all feedback so we may better answer in the future.

Answer (score 0):

This should start you off this formula is in the B column (B2)

```
=IF(A1=10,C3, if (a1 =12, c4,  if (a1 =14, C5,  if.......
```

The problem is this can get out of hand quickly.

Simply your using the false section of the formula to evaluate another equation