# Multiple conditions in a single Excel formula

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010

I want to be able to have the cells in Column F set so that if I have the adjacent cell in column E say something then it will display a certain number.

Cell e and F are currently set has lists if cell E says medium I want the adjacent cell in column F to say 180 days if its says High I want the adjacent cell in column F to say 30Days can if it says Critical I want the adjacent cell to 7 days. I currently have them both set has lists but when I have a lot of items to place in excel I was hoping to make this a bit faster.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I use multiple IF functions in Excel 2010?](http://superuser.com/questions/592404/how-can-i-use-multiple-if-functions-in-excel-2010)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it's just those 3 options you mentioned, then you can use this formula in column F:

`=IF(E1="Critical","7 Days",IF(E1="High","30 Days",IF(E1="Medium","180 Days","")))`

This is for the first line so it refers to cell E1. You can drag the formula across your entire column F and it will refer to the respective E cells.

Comment: thank you the formula works great, how do I get rid of the "False"

Comment: I edited the formula above to handle other values or empty cells, so you won't get "FALSE" for them.